# how to access phpmyadmin remotely

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, wampserver

Is it possible to access phpmyadmin from outside the network?
Where do I set it? I tried editing httpd.conf, and restarted all services from wampserver but it doesn't work

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you mean by outside the network, and what error was reported.

Comment: trying to access phpmyadmin like this: 192.xxx.x.x/phpmyadmin, I got access denied error

Comment: I think you'd need to specify which directory you want to configure in httpd.conf

Comment: You can't use the internal network IP to access phpmyadmin from outside the network, you'll need to use the external IP address =)

Answer (score 15):

Go to C:\wamp\alias and edit the file phpmyadmin

```
# to give access to phpmyadmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
#    Order Deny,Allow
#    Deny from all
#    Allow from 127.0.0.1
#
# by
#
#   Order Allow,Deny 
#   Allow from all
```

Answer (score 9):

```
# Edit C:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf  
# Below is v3.5.1 - the current version is 4.0.4.1

Alias /phpmyadmin "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/" 

# to give access to phpMyAdmin from outside 
# replace the lines
#
# Require local
#
# by
#
# Require all granted
#

<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.5.1/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
   AllowOverride all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: This should be the #1 answer

Comment: Good Answer!! you saved my time :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you on Unix or Windows? If on Unix, check the owner/permissions for the directory that phpMyAdmin is installed under - that might have something to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me as if you're trying to access a private address from a remote network. You can't. You will have to configure a webserver on your machine and use a ddns (in case you don't have a fixed public ip) service on your server. You will probablly have to redirect port 80 incoming traffic on your router pointing to the webserver machine also.

Answer (score 2):

just for reference of other users who will encounter this kind of issue I would like to remind everyone that aside from changing directories, you must also have to check your firewall settings.

It happened to me, I've changed everything (all config in xampp) but still cannot connect. I almost gave up and then I remembered firewall. After I changed my settings it all works fine.

**just sharing**

Answer (score 1):

Did you try like this ? Maybe you shuld add directory name in your network ?

```
<Directory "/Documents and Settings/All Users/Documents/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
...
...
...
...
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put below code in file
D:\wamp\alias\phpmyadmin.conf

< Directory "D:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin3.2.0.1/">

```
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
```

< /Directory>