# How to allow remote access to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I am running a Linux server with Apache2 and PHPMyAdmin installed. I am able to login remotely with my root account but not the account that was created for someone else. The new user has his host settings to "%" like it should be. However when I try to login with his account I get the error...

```
#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server
```

Might anyone be able to help me? I know there was supposed to be something like added to a file to allow permission but I can't seem to get it to work.

**RESOLVED:** I figured out the way to fix it. I had to go into SSH and use the command "mysql_secure_installation" and answer the questions :) Thanks everyone! I hope this helps others who have the same problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to access phpmyadmin remotely](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367330/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-remotely). And it took me exactly 5.7 seconds of Googling, with your *exact* title. ("How to allow remote access to phpmyadmin")

Comment: I've also Google'ed it too and all the pages that talk about it do not help me.

Comment: Did the linked question not help you too?

Comment: I used a similar guide to alter my apache2/sites-enabled/000-default file and made it include what was mentioned.

Comment: Why don't you answer your own question, accept it and show how you solved it! That way others will benefit too.