# How can I put phpmyadmin online using xampp?

Tags: android, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am writing web-services for Android and don't know how to put phpmyadmin online for outside access.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to SO. Please read how to create a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its help is given on appache friends website.
I also have try this and its working 
In the basic configuration of XAMPP, phpMyAdmin is accessible only from the same host that XAMPP is running on, at http://127.0.0.1 or http://localhost.

To enable remote access to phpMyAdmin, follow these steps:

Edit the apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf file in your XAMPP installation directory.
Within this file, find the line below and update it to remove 'phpmyadmin' from the list of locations.

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
```

Restart the Apache server using the XAMPP control panel.

**Hope this will help**

Answer (score 0):

PhpMyAdmin will, or should come installed on your web-host server if using a reputable hosting provider. In which case, the PhpMyAdmin panel will be accessible via your hosting panel dashboard once setup.

If you are going to be performing your own hosting you should most likely, download the latest (or required) version from the PHP.net site. And then installed to your server via command prompt or direct install.

Just follow the instructions on the website.

http://php.net/downloads.php

Comment: I want access as i enter ip/projectname from mobile or any other outside source @M. Williams

Comment: Please see the following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367330/how-to-access-phpmyadmin-remotely